# Hacer checkbox con datos traídos desde el controlador -laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

quisiera pedirles si me pueden ayudar con esto, quiero hacer un checkbox de una lista de datos que traigo desde mi controlador pero me da un error, aquí mi código en la vista:

```
@foreach($tipoPropiedad as $tipoPropiedad)
  <input type="checkbox" name="$tipoPropiedad[]" value="{{$tipoPropiedad}}"> <label>{{$tipoPropiedad}}</label>
@endforeach
```

y me da el siguiente error:

```
ErrorException {#293 ▼
  #message: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\mpe\storage\framework\views\6fe877a553adc88e744115568c7c6d45d04f8b32.php"
  #line: 45
  #severity: E_WARNING
}
```

Anteriormente tenía esto como una lista y funcionaba ok:

```
     {!! Form::label('tipoPropiedad', ' Tipo de propiedad del fundo') !!}
     <br>
     <select name ="tipoPropiedad" class="form-control"  >
     <option value= "Sin parametro">--Sin parámetro--</option>
     @foreach ($tipoPropiedad as $tipoPropiedad )
         <option value = "{{$tipoPropiedad}}"> {{$tipoPropiedad}}</option>
     @endforeach
     </select>
```

Y se veía así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí mi código en el controlador:

```
   public function index(){
      $cod_uso_suelo = DatoSuperficie::pluck('dsc_uso_suelo');
      $cod_uso_suelo = $cod_uso_suelo->unique();

      $restriccion = DatoSuperficie::where('cod_uso_suelo', 1031)->pluck('dsc_restriccion_suelo');
      $restriccion = $restriccion->unique();

      $especies = DatoSuperficie::where('cod_uso_suelo', 1031)->pluck('dsc_especie');
      $especies = $especies->unique();

      $codigos = DB::table('datos_superficies')->where('cod_uso_suelo',1031)->distinct()->pluck('cod_fundo');

      $a = 0;
      while ($a < count($codigos)) {
        $tipo = Fundo::where('cod_fundo',$codigos[$a])->pluck('dsc_tipo_propiedad');
        if ($a == 0) {
          $tipoPropiedad = $tipo;
        }
        else{
          $tipoPropiedad = $tipoPropiedad->concat($tipo);
        }
        $a++;

      }

      return view('filtro')->with('cod_uso_suelo', $cod_uso_suelo)
                          ->with('restriccion',$restriccion)
                          ->with('especies',$especies)
                          ->with('tipoPropiedad',$tipoPropiedad);
    }
```

Este es el contenido de `$tipoPropiedad`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar, saludos!

Comment: Estás sobreescribiendo la variable `@foreach($tipoPropiedad as $tipoPropiedad)` y, aparte, al parecer estás creando una cadena en lugar de un arreglo, algo cambiaste en el while, dentro del controlador.

Comment: Si es un arreglo, el metodo concat, me permite concatenar colecciones http://prntscr.com/r0vevc, y cambie el nombre de la variable y me da el mismo error

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el contenido de `$tipoPropiedad` antes de entrar al foreach

Comment: ahi, ya lo edite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tener solo el nombre:

```
@foreach($tipoPropiedad as $nombre)
  <input type="checkbox" name="tipoPropiedad[]" value="{{$nombre}}"> <label>{{$nombre}}</label>
@endforeach
```

Estabas poniendo `$tipoPropiedad[]` como nombre del campo y debe ir sin el `$`.

Comment: gracias, lo modifiqué tambien

Answer (score 0):

Bueno el primer punto es que estas queriendo recorrer un array cuando lo que devuelves no lo es, estas aplicando de manera inadecuada el foreach.
Luego de eso como sugerencia, deberías llamar el objeto completo y no solo una columna de la tabla,pues lo que le envías no es un array y también así puedes asignar valor y nombres distintos en las propiedades de la vista. Podrías aplicar el siguiente ejemplo.

```
@if (is_array($tipoPropiedad) || is_object($tipoPropiedad))
    @foreach ($tipoPropiedad as $key => $tipo)
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{$tipo->dsc_tipo_propiedad}}" value="{{$tipo->cod_fundo}}"> <label>{{$tipo->dsc_tipo_propiedad}}</label>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: mm es que si es un array https://prnt.sc/r0vevc mm
probé con lo que me sugeriste y me da el siguiente error: 
"Trying to get property 'dsc_tipo_propiedad' of non-object"

Answer (score 0):

se solucionó, no sé bien el motivo del porqué, pero borré todo lo que tenía en la vista y lo hice de nuevo, el código del controlador lo mantuve igual, es decir, `$tipoPropiedad` sigue siendo mi lista de `dsc_tipo_propiedad`

Gracias a todos los que se molestaron en responder :)

```
@foreach($tipoPropiedad as $tipo)
  <input type="checkbox" name="tipoPropiedad[]" value="{{$tipo}}"> <label>{{$tipo}}</label>
  <br>
@endforeach
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me extraña que se haya solucionado, porque corregiste todos los errores, pero agregaste otro al omitir los corchetes en el nombre del checkbox, ahora no importa si marcas uno o los 3, siempre recibirás solamente uno porque quedan con el mismo nombre en lugar de ser un array. Prueba con mi respuesta.

Comment: gracias, si, si me di cuenta, añadí los corchetes, gracias

Comment: Recuerda por favor marcarla como aceptada si te resolvió el problema